# AWS Reserved Instance expiration notifications [Exist??]

Tags: amazon-web-services

Good afternoon,

1. When EC2 **Reserved** Instance expire do we get notification?
2. How many weeks/day before?
3. Is there a settings page to adjust notification settings?

Comment: I can't really understand why this got downvotes...

Answer (score 3):

They just released RI Expiration alerts today! They're in the top right-hand corner of the RI Summary page in Cost Explorer: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/reservation-expiration-alerts-now-available-in-aws-cost-explorer/

Starting today, you can use AWS Cost Explorer’s new reservation expiration alerts capabilities to receive email alerts 60, 30, or 7 days in advance of your reservation expiration date, as well as on the date of expiration. These notifications can be sent to up to 10 email recipients.

To turn on reservation expiration alerts, navigate to the Reservation Summary page, locate the reservation expiration Key Performance Indicator (KPI) in the top right corner, and click on the “Manage alerts” link. From there, simply indicate when you would like to receive reservation expiration alerts, and AWS will begin monitoring your reservation portfolio and automatically send you alerts.

Answer (score 1):

It's frustrating there isn't a good AWS based solution but there are a few third party services which allow you to receive notifications depending on what exactly you need.

- https://www.cloudyn.com/
- https://www.cloudability.com/
- https://rimind.io/ (disclaimer, I'm one of the developers of rimind)

Comment: Could you explain how these services solve the problem stated in the question?

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no notification. You will need to keep an eye on your reservations and re-purchase them as necessary.

Comment: Does this stand true nowadays?